# What does putting a '|' on function parameter do?

Tags: c++

I am learning how to write SDL program in C++, and I came across this code:

```
SDL_Renderer *ren = 
    SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
//                                                       ^ I have no idea what this means?
```

I don't know if this is a specific C++ feature?

My guess coming from shell scripting background suggests it could be a pipe (I know it's obviously not that), or it's just a bitwise OR?

What does a `|` mean when using it in a function parameter like the above code?

Comment: See [bitwise logic operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators).

Comment: It's bitwise OR'ing operator. `01 | 10 = 11`

Comment: Very useful googlestring: "C++ operators". If you have a book, the operators are in the index. (You're going to want to look up more of them.) If you don't have a book, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) before you buy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are flags which you can set. In this instance `|` refers to the bitwise operator.

In your example, this conveniently allows you to combine multiple flags through a single parameter.

Suppose the two flags have the following values:

```
SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE = 1 // Binary 0001
SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED = 2 // Binary 0010
SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC = 4 // Binary 0100
```

A logic bitwise OR of the two, would leave you with the value 6 for the `flag`.
We can easily determine from this value which flags have been set using bitwise AND.:

```
flag = SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC // flag = 6 (0110)
flag & SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE == 0 // Not set
flag & SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED == 2 // Set
flag & SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC == 4 // Set
```

Note that it's important here for the flags to be powers of two, to ensure all flag combinations result in a unique value.

Comment: so it essentially means it passes both options SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED and SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC to CreateRenderer, right?

Comment: @hoholee12 Correct.

Comment: maybe you could edit your answer to have something like this: 1 == 0001, 2 == 0010, 4 == 0100, 6 = 0110 so that anyone like me can understand better

Answer (score 0):

The `|` is the [bitwise OR operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic), and in this case it is used to pass a set of flag to the `SDL_CreateRenderer` function.

Imagine a set of flag:

```
const int FLAG1 = 0x1 << 0; // 0b00...0001
const int FLAG2 = 0x1 << 1; // 0b00...0010
const int FLAG3 = 0x1 << 2; // 0b00...0100
/* ... */
```

As you can see from the binary representation of these flags, they only have one bit set to `1`, and this bit is different for each flag, meaning that you can combine them using the `|` operator...

```
int flag_a = FLAG1 | FLAG2; // 0b00...0011
int flag_b = FLAG1 | FLAG3; // 0b00...0101
```

...while still being able to retrieve the original flags using the bitwise AND (`&`) operator:

```
int is_flag1_set = flag_a & FLAG1; // 0b00...0001 != 0
int is_flag2_set = flag_a & FLAG2; // 0b00...0010 != 0
int is_flag3_set = flag_a & FLAG3; // 0b00...0000 == 0
```